# assigning constant char pointers to structure

Tags: c, pointers

So I havent taken a programming class in a while combined with being terrible with pointers and could really use some help

```
struct Base10Parse
{
  const char *p;
{
```

and then im trying to asign something like 1.3e5

```
int atof(const char *ptr)
{
  struct Base10Parse *Bp;
  Bp->p=ptr;
  

  return 0;
}
```

but i cant figure out how to assign it?
Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Are you getting a compile error? Is the code not behaving as you want?

Comment: my program explodes due to the Bp->p=ptr: line
explodes meaning no compiler error and the program sturts but then stops working and closes itself

Comment: In the future please explain your issue better by describing the exact problems/errors you get. For this question you have an answer already.

Comment: Self deprecation usually looks bad in questions (you're giving people ammunition to fire at you for digging yourself into a hole). I'd advise you not to do it if you want better answers.

Comment: consider editing your subject for correct English to `assigning constant char pointers to struct`.  You also are using an open curly bracket where it should be close for `struct Base10Parse`, and be aware the function name `atof` is a pre-defined function in `stdlib.h`

Comment: Buffer Pad: I'd like to advise you to take a new course or follow a new tutorial. There is lot to learn before learning pointers, they are almost useless nowadays for simple programs. For a start, replace your `const char*` by `std::string` (after having `#include`ed `<string>`) and you're good to go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a pointer `Bp` but left it uninitialised. You are getting a `Segmentation fault`, aren't you? Next time, **please say what error you are getting**.

You probably want to change :

```
struct Base10Parse *Bp;
Bp->p=ptr;
```

To:

```
struct Base10Parse Bp;
Bp.p=ptr;
```

If you really want Bp to be a pointer because you know what you're doing, then you should do :

```
struct Base10Parse *Bp = (Base10Parse*)malloc(sizeof(Base10Parse));
Bp->p=ptr;

// Do your code here, and the very end:

free(Bp);
```

In that case, you should `#include <stdlib.h>` at the beginning of your file.

**Unrelated suggestion**

Try changing

```
struct Base10Parse
{
    const char *p;
};
```

To :

```
typedef struct
{
    const char *p;
} Base10Parse;
```

That way, you can just declare `Bp` with `Base10Parse Bp;` instead of `struct Base10Parse Bp;`.

Comment: Thank you this fixxed it. I am really bad with pointers and apparently structures.

Comment: Then might I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)? It's a C++ tutorial, but C mostly works the same. By the way, if you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: @BufferPad Might I recommend [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/) ? It's a C++ tutorial, but C mostly works the same. :) *Please*, though, look for an answer online. **Google is your friend.**

Comment: I disagree with your last advise. In C I find it annoying, in C++ there is _absolutely no use_ to `typedef` a `struct`. `struct S{}; S s;` is valid code, no `struct` is needed to qualify the `S` type. Remember that, in C++, `struct` and `class` are almost synonyms; you wouldn't write `typedef class {} C;`, would you?

Comment: @YSC I 100% unserstand your viewpoint. This is really a question of opinion. If you're using a pure C compiler, it mignt reduce the syntax constraint a bit, but if you're using a C++ compiler, then indeed my advice is useless. In his case, it seems he's using a C compiler because of the `struct S s;` syntax, so I gave him a C advice.

Comment: But, once again, even with pure C, whether to `typedef` or not *is* really just a question of opinion. My opinion is that, if you're a programmer working on C everyday, you may (or not!) prefer not to have to worry about whether your variable is a struct or an enum, etc. How many variables do you think a programmer declares everyday?